# What cell provider should I use in Dubai?

Tags: international-travel, cellphones, mobile-operators

Planning a trip to Dubai/Sharjah in November from the US.  I've found two cell providers over there. Has anyone had experience with either provider?  Are there any others I should consider?

- [Du](http://www.du.ae/en/default)
- [Etisalat](http://www.etisalat.ae/)

Etisalat's website doesn't seem to have any pricing info for US travelers.  Du is a little more helpful.  Seems like they charge the following:

- Connection Fee     AED 49
- Free recharge card included    AED 20

Is it really 69 AED (18 USD) just to get the SIM card?

Comment: This is a shopping question, and as such, not allowed on any SE site.

Comment: Not sure I understand what a shopping question means.  Is it because I put the prices of the SIM Card? Or because I listed two providers?  Should I just simply ask "What cell provider should I use in Dubai" without listing providers?